# tcpdump -vvv is not verbose enough

Tags: networking, wireshark, tcpdump, packet-capture

For tcpdump, I use this command to see the packet details:

```
tcpdump -vvv -i interface
```

and to save the packets into a pcap file:

```
tcpdump -i interface -w output
```

The details from the first command are less than the details that are being put into the pcap file using the second command.

How can I see the same details in the terminal?

Answer (score 7):

> The details from `tcpdump -vvv -i interface` are less than the details that are being put into the pcap file using `tcpdump -i interface -w output`.

That is correct.

With `-w` the full raw packet gets saved while otherwise tcpdump runs its internal parser to generate what the [manual](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) calls *"a **description** of the packet data"*. (And not the *"fully decoded"* packet data.)

With `-vvv` you've also only selected one option (*"even more verbose"*)  of the command line options that `tcpdump` supports, but that single options doesn't cover the whole range of decoding options that is supported. There are more options in the [manual](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) that tune what gets displayed which might be useful (depending on your needs).

For example with only the `-vvv` option the displayed packet description does not include the information you see when you add `-e`.

And regardless, the capabilities and decoding powers of that tcpdump internal packet parser fall short to capabilities of a full packet analyser (with all kinds protocol decoding plugins) like Wireshark.

---

I often find it useful  to use the `--print` option in combination with `-w` to get tcpdump to both print the parsed packet description to my console, while the full packet data gets saved to pcap file for further analyses.

I can see on the console and confirm that the event I want to analyse has been captured, stop `tcpdump` and then also have the pcap file to load in Wireshark for more detailed analyses.